# Why does my reveal.js PDF output have 45 000 pages instead of 350 pages after upgrading from 2.6.2 to 3.5.0?

Tags: reveal.js

I recently upgraded [this slidedeck](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/slides/optaplanner-presentation/index.html) from reveal.js 2.6.2 to 3.5.0. Everything works fine, except that [the PDF export](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/slides/optaplanner-presentation/index.html?print-pdf#/) now has 45 000 pages instead of 350 pages like before the upgrade.

To reproduce, [click on this link](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/slides/optaplanner-presentation/index.html?print-pdf#/) and ask for the print dialog in Chrome, which will already show the number of pages.

My `index.html` hasn't changed. It has still this code:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.search.match(/print-pdf/gi)) {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css">');
    }
</script>
```

Which is still equivalent to [the PDF export instructions](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#pdf-export) in the latest readme.

Comment: It seems to be related to the use of `position: absolute;` paragraphs. As soon as those render, they add x number of blank pages.

Comment: Not sure how to get rid of the position absolute usages though.

Comment: [Regression from reveal.js 2 to 3.](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/2004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of reveal.js 3, [there is a regression](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/2004) that cannot handle overlapping images with `position: absolute` well in PDF export.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the PDF export instructions](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#page-size),

> Slides that are too tall to fit within a single page will expand onto multiple pages.

When I opened your presentation in browser based on Chromium, I saw quite a lot of empty space between slides. I think the problem may be somewhere here.